# Disable Specific days in asp calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, calendar

I am doing a software of soccer field bookings and i want to show the user a calendar showing him the days he can pick that are available. everytime someone make a booking on that day I want to disable that day in the calendar?
do i have to use the ondayrender?

```
 <asp:Calendar Visible="true" CssClass="date" ondayrender="DisabledDays_DayRender" ID="DisabledWeekendsCalendar" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>

  protected void DisabledDays_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: You must prove that you do a little search ... Stack Overflow is not a "Give Me The Answer". You must consider doing you own search.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a CustomValidator so that on submit it checks the days you want disabled and if the user has chosen one simply display an appropriate error message?

[Custom Validators - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)